# Trouble creating CFAttributedString after upgrade to Xcode 6.3 with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, core-foundation

My code, that draws an CFAttributedString into a graphic context, used to work fine before the update to Xcode 6.3.

Now, after the upgrade, I get the following errors:

```
'_' is not convertible to 'CFString!'
```

and

```
'[String : AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'
```

for the lines of code that define the attributes for the string:

```
let attributes : [String:AnyObject] = [
            kCTForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor,
            kCTFontAttributeName:font
        ]
```

This is how I draw the text:

```
var attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil,myString,attributes)
        var line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)
        var lineWidth = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(line, CTLineBoundsOptions.UseGlyphPathBounds).width
        var lineHeight = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(line, CTLineBoundsOptions.UseGlyphPathBounds).height
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, transformScale)
        CGContextSetTextPosition(context, (rect.width - lineWidth)/2, rect.height - lineHeight*1.5)
        CTLineDraw(line, context)
```

I tried to cast kCTForegroundColorAttributeName and kCTFontAttributeName with adding "as String" after them. This removed the errors but the strings didn't seem to get the attributes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do? Why store these as Strings? and this makes no sense you are making the name of the color the key and the font is then the value?

Comment: I'm creating a graphic with text. See my edit on how I draw the text.

Comment: I'm a fan of always showing what you're trying to do. Maybe update the post with the code. There's probably a better way.

Comment: see my edit, below the line "This is how I draw the text"

Comment: Why are you using the CF classes instead of NSAttributedString?

Comment: Because I'm programatically creating a graphic, which has other elements to it. If I only needed text, I would have used a UILabel. The code used to work before the new version of Swift, so Im hoping there is a way to fix this without rewriting the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the formatting and by replacing kCTForegroundColorAttributeName with NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Here is the fixed line:

```
let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor,
            NSFontAttributeName : font
        ]
```